# morphism of dual abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over an algebraically closed field.

My question is

Dose there exist an ample line bundle $L$ on $A$, such that the morphism $f_{L}: A \longrightarrow A'$ defined by $L$, where $A'$ is the dual abelian variety of $A$, is etale morphism?

Comment: No: look at one of the answers to the old question "non-principally polarized complex surfaces" for examples of abelian surfaces in characteristic $p$ such that any polarization has degree divisible by $p$ and hence is not etale (as the kernel of a polarization is self-dual).

Comment: By the way, the core content of the proof of Norman and Oort that abelian varieties in char. p always lift to char. 0 is *all about* how to deal with abelian varieties having no etale polarization (equivalently: no polarization with degree not divisible by $p$).  The lifting problem is (relatively) elementary when there is an etale polarization, but much much more work was needed to handle the general case.